# Find products by specifications with Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: c#, amazon-product-api

I am trying to find smartphones with the amazon product advertising api.
http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

On the amazon website you can set various filters like "storage" "features keywords".
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=n%3A2335752011%2Cn%3A!2335753011%2Cn%3A2407749011&bbn=2335753011&ie=UTF8&qid=1361393129&rnid=2335753011

For example I want to find smartphones from Samsung with Android OS that are cheaper than 250 USD with at least 32 GB storage.

```
        ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();            
        request.SearchIndex = "Electronics";
        //this browsenode is for amazon.de (cell phones)
        request.BrowseNode = "1384526031";
        request.MaximumPrice = "250";
        // ? request.Storage = 32 
        // ? request.OperatingSystem = "Android"            
        request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "Large" };

        ItemSearch itemSearch = new ItemSearch();
        itemSearch.AssociateTag = "xxx";
        itemSearch.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };
        itemSearch.AWSAccessKeyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessKeyId"];

        ItemSearchResponse response = amazonClient.ItemSearch(itemSearch);

        foreach (var item in response.Items[0].Item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ItemAttributes.Title);
        }
```

My problem is that the ItemSearchRequst class doesn't have properties like "storage" or "features" or "operating system".

Answer (score 0):

I have been finding this information for more than a week but there is indeed no documentation for this feature. I believe Amazon wants to keep this, together with product technical detail and product reviews for itself. However you can filter some of these keywords (such as operating system), but not all, from `itemsearch` with `responsegroup('Large')`